# How to recover a broken JSON database using Python (letters of product names where replaced along with prices going from numbers to strings mode)

Tags: python, json

So the company I am doing internship to gave me a challange I can't seem to do it (it's ok, they said I could ask for help). They want me to "fix" a broken database, starting by the name that went from:

```
"name": "iPhone XS Max Prata"
```

to

```
"name": "iPhøne XS Mæx Prætæ"
```

And I need to change it back to normal but can't by any means I try.
They also want me to change string to number as:

```
"price": "1250.00"
```

to

```
"price": 1250.00
```

Using python and a JSON file. Could anyone give me some help/tips please?

I have tried the following codes but it just messes up the list even more, adding a bunch of numbers and random letters to it.

````
import json
with open("broken_database.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    broken_database = json.load(file)
    for case in broken_database:
        if case["name"] in ["ø", "æ", "ß", "¢"]:
           case["name"] = ["o", "a", "b", "c"]

with open("broken_database.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(broken_database, file, indent=2)

print(broken_database)






I expected the letters to be swapped but instead I got:

```
"id": 5677240,
    "name": "C\u00f8njunt\u00f8 de P\u00e6nel\u00e6s \u00e6nti\u00e6derentes \u00a2\u00f8m 05 Pe\u00e7\u00e6s P\u00e6ris",
    "quantity": 21,
    "price": "192.84",
    "category": "Panelas"
```

And I have no idea how to change the strings to numbers, as I said this is my first time with JSON.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a "challenge", I'm going to give you some hints first rather than a full solution.

First of all: your code at the moment isn't breaking anything. When Python outputs JSON, it "escapes" all characters higher than 0x7F, writing them in the form `\u0000` or `\u00000000`. `\u00f8` means exactly the same thing as `ø`, but the former is safer to pass around on the internet (since some old-fashioned systems freak out when you give them values higher than 0x7F). At the moment, your code isn't actually changing the data at all!

Second of all: you don't want to check if `case[name] in [...]`. Consider: is `'mæx'` in `['æ', 'ø']`? Look into the function `str.replace`.

Third of all: for converting strings to numbers, the `int` and `float` functions are your friends. In this case you'll want `float`.

P.S. If you're having trouble reading the "escaped" strings, open Python in a terminal and put the string in. It'll show you the actual Unicode.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried the replace function but it gives me the following:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Is there a specific replace method for json?

Comment: I have tried 
`for i, word in enumerate(broken_database):`
       `if word == "æ":`
          `broken_database[i] = "a"`
But also did'nt work :(

Comment: @AliciaAlves Consider. Will the name ever be **equal to** `'æ'`? (Answer: no it won't.) What should you be checking instead? Similarly, `replace` is a method on strings, not lists. What do you want to call `replace` on?

Comment: I should be checking the individual characters but I'm not sure how to do it. I wanted to use the replace function to replace the individual wrong characters everytime they show up on the list by the correct ones, as I normally would do in a string.

Comment: I never had to replace individual characters in the middle of words in a list before, I tried writing a function to do so but it always comes back with an error so I don't know how I should go about this one

Comment: @AliciaAlves How would you replace characters in a string? (Hint: `str.replace`.) Now you're already running through all the strings in the database. All you have to do is run the replacement on each one.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it still gives me errors, it says that the attribute doesn't exist or that the 'list' object can't have that attribute, either way it won't replace the characters as I need to

Comment: This is the last error I got `"str.replace("æ", "a")
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)"`

Comment: @AliciaAlves Don't call it on the list. Call it on the string.

Comment: But how do I call it on the string specifically? I'm so sorry but I don't understand what you meant (I have started to learn programming about 5 weeks ago, a lot of this is still very very new to me)

Comment: @AliciaAlves `case['name'] = case['name'].replace(whatever)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I've managed to do both things now (change the characters and change the str to float). One last question if that is ok, what if some of the products lost it's price attribute alltogether, how can I add it on only those who lost it (put it "price" = 0)?

Comment: PS: I did try the `.append` function but as expected it just added to the end of the list and that's not quite what I wanted

Comment: @AliciaAlves It's just like assigning a variable. `case['name'] = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) module, as well as the `ensure_ascii=False` parameter with `json.load`.